# How to get default xorg.conf back?

Tags: xorg

I accidentally modified my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. Can I just delete it or I am toasted? Is there anything I should be worried about. I'm not having any issue except the twitchy/shaky touchpad. I have a Dell Inspiron n4050. How can I get my default xorg.conf back? and if possible how can I remove the twitchy/shaky touchpad? I saw a lot of threads regarding this issue but I could not get the solution to it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default on Ubuntu is to not have an xorg.conf. Just removing it should be fine. If you're using the proprietary Nvidia drivers, you may need to just re-run the `nvidia-settings` tool, and have it write out a new xorg.conf. I don't have an answer for the touchpad though.

Comment: Now I just need to remove this twitchy/shaky touchpad problem. It's so annoying and irritating. When I hold my finger on the touchpad, the touchpad goes SUPER SENSITIVE and the cursor, it's like rotating here and there around where it should have been. Duh :/, does anyone have a solution to it? I have a Dell Touchpad.